# How to access whole sub python file from parent in order to use as parameter plus structure of python progr. with modules

Tags: python

I have learned, that I can structure my REUSABLE parts of Python in modules and packages.

But how do I structure a program? Also as a package!?

First, I have my "main.py" program. This is the entry point to my program. Then I want to have
for instance two sub directories "core" and "components" and in "core" a python file named "general.py" with several functions.

How do I access the whole sub python file "general.py" ("core" directory) from the "main.py" file in order to take it as a parameter for a function??

Can anybody show me the possible structure of program with multiple modules?

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories work the same as modules, except that they require a `__init__.py` file in them to be considered as python modules. This file doesn't need to contain anything. To access python modules inside module directories, use a point like

```
import core.module
```

At the end you have

```
main.py
core/
    __init__.py
    module.py
```

This the simple answer, but actually python packages are more complex than just that and you should [read about them](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).